# How to add a URL and Buttons on top of an existing header Image

Tags: html, css

1) I have a header JPEG image that spans a width of 996px that has a square logo to the left of this header.

My question is that I would like to use this square logo section only and place a `href` tag so that when the user hover's over this section only, the cursor changes to a hand pointer and the user will be redirected back to the landing page.

2) On this same image, I would also like to place two buttons with rollover effects, so when the user hovers over the buttons, the rollover effect takes control and then would like these buttons to also point to a `href` url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an `<img>` tag to display the image, you can use a simple [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) to make only a section of the image a link.

As for number 2, I'm not clear on what effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, just want to be able to add two buttons to an existing images that would go to a particular URL and when you hover over the buttons, would like the look of the buttons to change color, let's say. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatly image maps can't be styled which means you will need to use absolute positioning to position div's over the image to get your desired effect.